# Error in replicating example on w3schools

Tags: javascript, null

```js
let x = document.getElementById("txt");
setTimeout(function(){ x.value="2 seconds"}, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){ x.value="4 seconds" }, 4000);
setTimeout(function(){ x.value="6 seconds" }, 6000);
```

```html
 <input type="text" id="txt">
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value') ( I get this )
I searched for solution but couldn't find anywhere. Would be glad if anyone can help me

I wanted to see 2 seconds, 4 seconds and 6 seconds consecutively in input.

Comment: I reformatted your snippet and it works for me.

Comment: code is working for me also

Comment: You will see the error if your setup is like this: https://jsfiddle.net/d1y9x5ch/ . You can prevent the error either by moving the `<script>...</script>` to the bottom of your code, or by doing this: https://jsfiddle.net/d1y9x5ch/1/

Comment: I used external JS file actually. I tried document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {} .I didn't understand why but it worked. Thank you my friend

Answer (score 0):

let me try to explain, the js engine reads the file synchronously, it sees the  tag, it starts reading the code written in the js file, but since the html file is not yet fully loaded, so the code does not work correctly, this photo clearly shows it, there is a defer attribute, which is a good solution to this problem (this problem can also be solved if you drop the script tag at the end of the html code), the photo shows that with the help of defer, js code is loaded simultaneously with html parsing, here is the defer syntax `<script src="demo_defer.js" defer></script>`

[image]